# can i combine these css classes into one css class?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Can i change this code to somethign like the below code?

```
<style>
      .FirstLetter:first-letter{font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-bottom:3px;}
      .Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;}
      </style>

<div class="FirstLetter Spaced headerFont">
Executive Summary
</div>


 <style>
 .Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-bottom:3px;}
 </style>
    <div class="Spaced">
    Executive Summary
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is supposed to work. Why didn't you just try it, are you afraid to blow something up?

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the pseudo element for the first letter for the div (the "E"), but unless you want to apply specific styling to the letter then you should have faster loading code without that line